# Did I break the C compiler?

Tags: c, string

Can anyone explain why this is splitting on both `char s` and `char poooooop`?
It does not seem like this should be using both delimiters.. Is this a bug or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?
Using GCC compiler

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){
   char str[80] = "something:27393 somethingElse:11 info:3";
   const char s[1] = " ";

   char* token;
   char* nextToken;

   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(str, s);
   const char poooooop[1] = ":";

   printf("%s\n", poooooop);
   printf("%s\n", s);
   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token );
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }

   return(0);

}
```

Comment: no you didnt break the compiler (without even reading the question)

Comment: Change your "funny" title before it started to collect downvotes...

Comment: Use char pooop[ ] = " ";. Thus, the null character is appended to the end of the array.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Too late.

Answer (score 4):

The second parameter of `strtok` is required to be a pointer to a string. Your `s` in

```
token = strtok(str, s);
```

stands for a `const char *` pointer, which is is not a pointer to a string. The behavior is undefined. The strange behavior you observed is just a manifestation of that undefined behavior.

A string is defined as a zero-terminated sequence of characters. Your `s` is not a zero-terminated sequence of characters. It is an array that contains a single space character. In your declaration of `s` the zero-terminator character present in the `" "` literal is "lost" due to insufficient size of `s` array. Standard C language allows this to happen.

If you want that array to contain a zero-terminator character, you have to declare it with size 2 (at least)

```
const char s[2] = " ";
```

or simply

```
const char s[] = " ";
```

or

```
const char *s = " ";
```

as suggested in the comments.

P.S. The same applies to your `poooooop` array.

Answer (score 0):

You set up your strings incorrectly.

```
  const char s[1] = " ";
```

should be

```
  const char *s = " ";
```

Surprising that the compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: That's a perfectly valid array initialization. It is just not a nul-terminated string.

Comment: @Quentin.: Printing it and using it where null terminated char array is required  - is problem.

Comment: the compiler can see the size mismatch - 2 chars on one side and one char on the other. you would think it would warn

Comment: @pm100 no, you are [explicitly allowed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization#Initialization_from_strings) to skip the nul.

Comment: @pm100: It is a quintessential, perfect, distilled example of a situation that would warrant a genuine compiler *warning*. This is the very reason compiler warnings exist in the world. And yet GCC fails to warn even with `-Wall -Wextra`. What gives? Yet they generate barrages of useless warnings and report errors as warnings...

Comment: @Quentin: But that's what *warnings* are for. To inform the user about something that is formally *allowed*, but *looks suspicious*. This feature with allowing the terminating to drop is present in C language to support fixed-width strings. But nobody is using fixed-width strings anymore. C++ disallowed it a long time ago. Yet, GCC warns about multi-char character constants (which can be fairly useful), but is silent about this (!).

Comment: Indeed. Not illegal, perfectly allowed, almost certainly wrong -> warning.

Comment: @AnT that would require the compiler to trace `s` until its use in `strtok`, and correlate that with the fact that `strtok` expects a string. Not impossible, but unlikely.

Comment: @Quentin: No. No need to trace anything. Just warn immediately and unconditionally when the terminating zero does not fit into the array. If the user really wants this, they can rewrite it as `char s[1] = { ' ' };` and the warning will go away.

Comment: @AnT that would only report false positives. The explicit array size means that you *want* to drop the nul-terminator. If you want to keep it, let the size be deduced.

Comment: @Quentin: Majority of warnings are false positives. That's the reality of life. However, the explicit arrays size that drops the zero in 99% of such cases means that the user made a mistake, not that they want to drop the terminator. Again, if the user really wants to create a non-string - force them to use the `char s[1] = { ' ' };` syntax. End of story. When I write `'abc'` in my code it is quite possible that I *want* to use a multi-char character constant. However, GCC warns, since it believes that I simply mistakenly used `'` instead of `"`. This is exactly the same kind of situation.

Comment: In case of warnings, it is never possible to definitively determine whether the user made a mistake or done something deliberately. Which is why warnings are usually controllable at both the compiler settings level and code level. All I'm saying is that a warning like that is definitely warranted. Just give the user the means to suppress it when they really want to do something like that.

Comment: @AnT I personally don't buy that you'd accidentally declare an explicit size, *and* that it'd be exactly the right one in "99% of the cases". Bothering users in favour of learners who don't know about nul terminators not deduced array sizes doesn't seem to align with the current direction of C compilers. As for multibyte characters, they are warned about because they are underspecified, and thus non-portable. *That* one is a risk by itself.

Comment: @Quentin: The source of "exactly the right size" is rather obvious: the user sees only one character between the `"`, so the user specifies `1` as array size. Forgetting about the "invisible" zero character is a very widespread error among less experienced programmers. As for the more experienced programmers - they would probably never use this feature anyway since this attempt to save 1 byte brings more problems than its worth. In those special situations when precise control over the array size is required, they'd never use this feature either.

Comment: @AnT well if the compiler started barking useless warnings at them, of course they wouldn't ;) -- But all I'm saying is that the absence of a warning isn't "surprising" at all, since this is a well-defined feature used with a very specific syntax. Whether C compilers should be beginner-friendly at the expense of language features is another question, but apparently the answer for GCC is "no".

Comment: @Quentin: Um... But, again, that's the whole point of *warnings*, the reason they exist: to warn about *well-defined features*. Warnings do not in any way prevent usage of language features.

Comment: @AnT there's no flexibility in the initializer syntax, so that warning would completely prevent the use of a string literal since you can't work around it. You'd have to resort to that clunky `char` list. Since the convenience far outweighs the risk that a professional programmer would accidentally misuse that feature, it makes perfect sense that no warning is emitted. Note that chopping off one or more characters, however, does trigger an error.

Comment: @Quentin: The same can be said about huge number of other warnings that force us to use "clunky syntax" to suppress them.

Comment: @AnT these are the ones where the risk was deemed too high for the convenience :)

Comment: @Quentin: And that's exactly the group one this one falls into. Again, the feature is there to support fixed-width strings. Nobody uses fixed-width strings anymore. Nobody complains about the absence of this feature in C++ even when they write C-like code in C++.